# How to handle all standard Spring MVC exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've implemented my exception handler where I catch MY custom exceptions.
Now, I'm just wondering if there is a nice way to catch all the Exceptions defined in class:
`org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

Following the definition of handleException method:

```java
/**
 * Provides handling for standard Spring MVC exceptions.
 * @param ex the target exception
 * @param request the current request
 */
@ExceptionHandler({
    HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
    HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class,
    HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class,
    MissingPathVariableException.class,
    MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
    ServletRequestBindingException.class,
    ConversionNotSupportedException.class,
    TypeMismatchException.class,
    HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
    HttpMessageNotWritableException.class,
    MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
    MissingServletRequestPartException.class,
    BindException.class,
    NoHandlerFoundException.class,
    AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class
})
@Nullable
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) throws Exception {
...
}
```

So basically I want my `ExceptionHandler` to be hable to catch all the exceptions listed above. Preferably avoinding to override every single handle method.
I need this in order to send back to the client the classic json with status, errorMessage, timestamp, ecc.

Comment: Why do you handle so many exceptions with one exception handling class?
i think every customize exception should has it's own exception handler,bro
you can basic class of thoes exceptions and replace them.

Comment: what is the question here? you are already showing the code required to handle those exceptions.